# Not allowing the same player to be both players in a game

Tags: java, oop

I am making a model of an OOP where players can join games within a gaming platform. One of the criteria was not to allow the same person to be both people playing a game and now I am stuck on how to extend this for there being any number of maximum players

In the Player Class..

public class GameExt2{

```
    private final int minAge;   
    private final PlayerExt2[] players;
    private String gameName;
    private int gameId;
    private double fee;
    private double amountOwed;
    private double totalFeesOwed;
    private int numberOfPlayersPlaying;
    private String playerNames;
    private int oweLimit;
    private int maxNumberPlayers;



public GameExt2( String gameName, int gameId, int minAge, double fee, int oweLimit, int maxNumberPlayers){



    this.gameId=gameId;
    this.gameName=gameName;
    this.minAge=minAge;
    this.fee=fee;
    this.oweLimit=oweLimit;
    this.players=new PlayerExt2[maxNumberPlayers];


    public String matchId(PlayerExt2 player){
        return("Sorry " + player.getName()+ ", you cannot be both players");
}





    public String isTooYoung(PlayerExt2 player){
        return("Sorry " + player.getName()+ ", you are too young to play" +gameName);
}





    public String maxPlayersReached(PlayerExt2 player){
        return("Sorry " + player.getName()+ ", there are already "+maxNumberPlayers+ " playing");
}





    private void playerJoined(PlayerExt2 player){
        System.out.println(player.getName() + " has joined the game " + gameName);          
    }






   public void addPlayer(PlayerExt2 player) {
        int nextFreeSlot = getNextFreeSlot();
        if (nextFreeSlot > 0) {
            if (isEligible(player)) {
                if (!isAlreadyPlaying(player)) {
                    players[nextFreeSlot] = player;
                    playerJoined(player);
                player.addGameJoined();
                player.addFeeOwed(fee);
                player.setNameGamePlaying(gameName);            //necessary for printing details of the player

                }
                else {
                    matchId(player);
                                                        // Already playing
                }
            }
            else {
              isTooYoung(player);
                                                        //player inelligible to play
            }
        }
        else {
            maxPlayersReached(player);
                                                            // game already full
        }
    }





    private boolean isAlreadyPlaying(PlayerExt2 newPlayer) {
        for (PlayerExt2 player : players) {
            if (player.getId() == newPlayer.getId()) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }





    private int getNextFreeSlot() {
        for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
            if (players[i] == null) return i;
        }
        return -1;                                          // negative indicates there's no free slot
    }





    private boolean isEligible(PlayerExt2 player) {
        return player.getAge() > minAge;
    }

Player class...




    public String addFeeOwed(double fee){

        amountOwed=amountOwed+fee;
        return("For playing this game of "+nameGamePlaying+ ", "+playerName+"'s balance now stands at £"+amountOwed);
}



    public void addGameJoined(){
        gamesJoined++;
}
```

a section of main...

```
    GameExt2 snakesAndLadders=new GameExt2("SnakesAndLadders",4564345,8,3,10,4);




    PlayerExt2 marina= new PlayerExt2(123, "Marina", 15, 4,1999,0);
    marina.calculateAge();
 System.out.println(marina.printDetails());
    snakesAndLadders.addPlayer(marina);



    PlayerExt2 erin=new PlayerExt2(163,"Erin",3,6,2010,0);
    erin.calculateAge();
System.out.println(erin.printDetails());
    snakesAndLadders.addPlayer(erin);




    PlayerExt2 matthew=new PlayerExt2(312,"Matthew",27,5,2002,12);
    matthew.calculateAge();
System.out.println(matthew.printDetails());
    snakesAndLadders.addPlayer(matthew);
```

Comment: If the `playerId` is unique, then wouldn't it be simply `playerOne.playerId != playerTwo.playerId`?

Comment: Why is there a method declaration in the constructor? (Guessing that you formatted it incorrectly)

Comment: @Andrew I suppose it was supposed to be two adjacent methods: the constructor, then `joinGame`. I just formatted what was there - it was a mess.

Comment: I've taken an educated guess of how your code was supposed to be structured. If you learned correct indentation, you would not have this problem.

Comment: Yes! Would this go in a conditional statement?(sorry to be so annoying,  I'm new to programming)

Comment: and what if then, the maximum number of players was not limited to 2?

Answer (score 2):

If you think about this should be structured conceptually, these are not constraints that a player should themselves enforce. In real life, a player does not care whether they are too young to play. In a tournament, that would be the responsibility of some administrator, or maybe a referee. We don't have to model this exactly but the point is that it should be outside of a player's control. I'd put this logic in a `Game` class, which `Player`s get added to.

You can see this having strange effects on your code already. Your player has a `numberOfPlayers` field. Does this make sense? Is `numberOfPlayers` a property of a person? Do you have that information on your passport or driver's license?

Here's a rough structure (not complete code)

```
class Game
{
    private final int minAge;
    private final Player[] players;

    public Game(int numberOfPlayers, int minAge) {
        //create array of the correct size, it will be filled with nulls
        this.players = new Player[numberOfPlayers];
        this.minAge = minAge;
    }

    void addPlayer(Player player) {
        int nextFreeSlot = getNextFreeSlot();
        if (nextFreeSlot > 0) {
            if (isEligible(player)) {
                if (!isAlreadyPlaying(player)) {
                    players[nextFreeSlot] = player;
                }
                else {
                    // Already playing
                }
            }
            else {
                // Ineligible
            }
        }
        else {
            // Full
        }
    }

    private boolean isAlreadyPlaying(Player newPlayer) {
        for (Player player : players) {
            if (player.getId() == newPlayer.getId()) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private int getNextFreeSlot() {
        for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
            if (players[i] == null) return i;
        }
        return -1; // negative indicates there's no free slot
    }

    private boolean isEligible(Player player) {
        return player.getAge() > minAge;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, I can't thank you enough! this makes much more sense, my way of thinking wasn't correct! I really appreciate you giving your time to help me out like this!

Comment: Even when you just have two players, I would still use a collection to "collect" all players. This avoids the `if (playerOne == null)` stuff and is much easier to adapt when allowing more players. Since we verify that no id is duplicated, we can even use a Set if the players doesn't need to be sorted (for example when they've joined).

Comment: @Tom I'm not sure I agree. Obviously if `n` players are required then a collection is the only way to solve it, but if it's always two players then I suspect that other methods in the Game will be easier to read if there are simply two fields. Difficult to know without knowing what the game is, but that's my suspicion. I'd probably go one further and have a `GameSignUp` or something (effectively a `GameFactory`) which enforces those constraints, then the game itself could be guaranteed to have 2 non-null fields at the point of instantiation.

Comment: is it possible to print out a messge ie "A new player has joined the game" within this method?

Comment: I'm very very grateful for all of this!
I'm guessing if the number of players wasn't limited to two for each game (ie some games had 4) then this would be a lot more complicated?

Comment: @MarinaCalder Not a lot, but maybe somewhat. Either use an array or a List for the players. If you struggle with changing that aspect of it, just post another question showing your attempt. Feel free to ping me here if you want me to look at it

Comment: I think I've reached my maximum question limit for the moment- I hate asking but it is a lot of trouble to post an example?

Comment: I feel like I've learned such a lot from you! Thank you SO much (sorry if i sound very repetitive!)

Comment: @MarinaCalder No problem. Happy to help

Comment: @Michael , Sorry to bug you again. I've edited my comment (instead of creating a new question because I can't) with my new code, but the output is coming out with inaccurate numbers in the printing, if even printing at all, have I done something obviously wrong?

Comment: @Michael I don't have enough reputation to add this to a chat

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:

- joinGame() should not be in the Player class. Placing this method is not extensible, however judging by the fact that it mentions the param nameGamePlaying which is not referenced in Player, this method is already in Game.class or whatever your equivalent is.
- If you want to compare whether two instances are meant to represent the same object, override the equals method, as a lot of methods in Java use it to compare, so doing so will save you a lot of hassle. The equals method should compare whether the two instances are *logically* equivalent, so in this case we should just need to compare playerId, however other classes could need other comparison fields.
- Don't hard code constants like maximum number of players. Your example is testament to that, because you actually want a maximum of 2 players, but coded the value 3. When you realise this mistake, or if you just want to increase the number of maximum players, you'll have to track down every occurrence of 3 and replace it. Instead, declare a constant MAX_PLAYERS at the class level, and reference that where necessary.
- You'll need to declare getters in Person.class for the below to work.
- Nest if statements to eliminate repetition. There's no need to constantly check the maximum number of players like you originally do, if you nest your subsequent logic within an if statement checking maximum number of players.

Code below, any questions please ask.

---

```
//In Game.class or equivalent
private final int MAX_PLAYERS = 2;
private List<Player> playerList; //Should be initialised with the main Game(?) class.
public String joinGame(Person player){
    if(playerList.size() < MAX_PLAYERS){
        if(!playerList.contains(player) && player.getPlayerAge() >= minAge){
            playerList.add(player)
            return (player.getPlayerName() + " has joined the game " + nameGamePlaying + ".");
        }else{
            return ("Sorry, " + player.getPlayerName()+ " is too young to play or is already playing " + nameGamePlaying);
        }
    } else {
        return ("Sorry, "+ player.getPlayerName()+ " cannot play " + nameGamePlaying + " as there are already two players.");
    }
}

//In Person.class
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if(this == obj){
        return true;
    }
    if(obj == null){
        return false;
    }
    if(getClass() != obj.getClass()){
        return false;
    }
    Person toCompare = (Person) obj;

    if(this.playerId != toCompare.getPlayerId()){
        return false;
    }

    //Optional, depending on your construct.
    if(playerName == null){
        if(toCompare.getPlayerName != null){
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        if(!playerName.equals(toCompare.getPlayerName(){
            return false;
        }
    }

    //... More logical equality checks

    return true;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for this! I've done a less complicated version as edited above, but It's giving me strange output numbers and messages, is there something wrong with what I have written from what you can see? @Andrew

Comment: Would need more information than just "strange output numbers and messages" to tell you more.

Comment: well for example, it won't let players join a game with a maximum of 4 players with an output of " game is full" when there is no one playing yet

Comment: For one, your players array has the modifier final. Look up what final does, and look up how to debug your programs to determine what does and doesn't get hit.

Comment: I've changed it to public, but still won't let players join

Comment: No, "final". Not the access modifier, the keyword "final" means that after initial assignment, an object is no longer modifiable. You initialise the array , and as it has the "final" modifier you can no longer alter the contents. If you want to add or remove players to the array, it cannot be final.

Comment: yes sorry, my brain is kind of panicking, that's what I meant, "final" is removed

Comment: Well then look up how to debug your code, it'll give you greater insight in to what's going wrong, and also it'll let you examine what different operations do to the state of your objects so you'll learn quicker. What IDE are you using?

Comment: No, but a debugger allows you to set breakpoints at different points which pause execution of the program when reached, so you can check if the states of the variables are as expected. http://plugins.jedit.org/plugins/?Debugger

Comment: I'm afraid that link is obsolete, do you know what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Oh my bad on the obsolete part, but still. I do not know what is wrong with your code, but it is your code and no one here is going to do all the work for you. Find a way to debug your code.

Comment: ok, well thanks anyway, any hints on how to not let a player join if they are in a game already?

Comment: I've already answered that, read the original comment about overriding equals.